Disabling clang language extensions
I was trying to demonstrate how clang has language extensions that allow code that does not conform to the standard to be compiled. I also wanted to show that these can be disabled.
I thought, however, that it was possible to do this (or at least have the compiler warn me) by using -pedantic and -pedantic-errors, however, when I compile the following code with clang -std=c99 -pedantic -pedantic-errors alpha.c -o alpha, I do not get any errors despite using const int with case statement. When I compile it with gcc -std=c99 alpha.c -o alpha, I get the expected errors
alpha.c: In function ‘func’:
alpha.c:9:3: error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant
    9 |   case a:
      |   ^~~~
alpha.c:12:3: error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant
   12 |   case b:
      |   ^~~~


alpha.c
#include <stdio.h>
const int a = 1;
const int b = 2;

void func(int c)
{
  switch (c)
  {
  case a:
    printf("HI\n");
    break;
  case b:
    printf("BYE\n");
    break;
  default:
    printf("Hmm\n");
    break;
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  int choice = 1;
  func(choice);
  return 0;
}

clang --version:
Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin


I am wondering: Is there a way to have clang warn me if my code is not standard-compliant?

(a) There is no question in your post. (b) The fact that code uses an extension does not mean it does not conform to the C standard. The standard specifies both conforming programs and strictly conforming programs. Conforming programs may use extensions. The C language was designed to be extended and for programs to use extensions. (c) The -pedantic switches does not disable all extensions in either Clang or GCC. Technically speaking, this is impossible because an extension is any additional specification to the language, and each implementation must, for example…

… choose what number of bits to use for int, and that becomes an extension to the language. In this and numerous other ways, any C implementation specifies more details for how it behaves than the broad allowances of the C standard. You cannot make a C implementation without specifying numerous details that the C standard leaves open.

What version of clang are you using (include clang --version in the question)? clang 18 rejects it (I tried a lot of older versions too, but they all rejected it)

I am using Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5). I found out that when I add the flag -Wgnu-folding-constant, clang does complain, but this solution seem to be more of "mimic GCC."

It seems like Apple configured building clang in a special way. What about the commonly used -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors, does that trigger the error?

doesn't clang does that already - https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#command-line-options:~:text=clang%20supports%20the%20%2Dstd,in%20an%20earlier%20mode.

If I try clang -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors alpha.c -o alpha, it compiles without any warnings or errors.

Ah... This is interesting: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/727530

Wow, that is interesting. Thank you for finding that. I think that answers the question.
